# operator overload for pointer structure in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, operator-overloading

What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

```
foo* f = foo(1) + foo(2) + foo(3)
```

to be the same as

```
foo* f = new foo[3];
f[0] = foo(1);
f[1] = foo(2);
f[2] = foo(3);
```

the code I have to do this is:

```
foo*& operator+(foo f){
     foo* ret = new foo[2];
     ret[0] = *this;
     ret[1] = f;
     return ret;
}
```

which will work for two, but I want to make it for a virtually unlimited amount. I have no idea where to start, and since I do not know what that is called, I cannot look it up.

Comment: This just does not look like a very good idea, at all. You shouldn't be using pointers or `new` in C++ in the first place...

Comment: @OP, tell us what *you* think `f[1] = foo(2)` does. (In reality, it does no well-defined thing.)

Comment: You should give us the context in which you're using foo. Your code makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a similar thing with `vector`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
  foo(int) {}
};

std::vector<foo>
operator+(const foo& lhs, const foo& rhs) {
  std::vector<foo> v;
  v.push_back(lhs);
  v.push_back(rhs);
  return v;
}

std::vector<foo>
operator+(std::vector<foo> lhs, const foo& rhs) {
  lhs.push_back(rhs);
  return lhs;
}

int main () { 
  std::vector<foo> f = foo(1) + foo(2) + foo(3);
}
```

But I can't imagine why you'd want to.

Comment: Note that in C++03, this won't be super efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a container which varies in size, just use std::vector like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int x) : x_(x) {}

private:
    int x_;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<Foo> fooContainer;

    fooContainer.push_back(Foo(1));
    fooContainer.push_back(Foo(2));
    fooContainer.push_back(Foo(3));

    return 0;
}
```

It may not be as "convenient" than using your operator version but there are multiple reasons why you shouldn't use it anyway. First and foremost, you shouldn't use pointers (at least not "naked" ones) and should avoid operator new due to the very high risk of memory leaks. The other reason is that your use of operator + does not actually represent a summation operation. When overloading operators you should make them act as they do on primitive types. When you do "2 + 3" the result is 5 aka the sum. What you're making operator + do here is not a sum you are creating a container from the elements and that is different than the expected meaning of operator +.

Comment: Or in C++11 you can write `std::vector<Foo> foo = {foo(1), foo(2), foo(3)};`  In C++03, [boost:assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) lets you `std::vector<Foo> foo; foo += foo(1),foo(2),foo(3);`.

Comment: Fair point, I'm haven't gotten around to all the new toys in C++11. Learn something new everyday.